# Adding a dictionary to the end of a list of tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm working on a problem and I'm a little confused about where to begin.

Here is the list I'm working with:

```
customers = list();
customer_list.append( {{'id':12345, 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Anderson','orders':[('order_1',300),('order_2',255),('order_3',79)]})
customer_list.append( {{'id':12346, 'first_name':'Mary', 
'last_name':'Smith','orders':[('Order_1' 400),('order_2',199),('order_3',49)]})
```

I need to pass a dictionary with an order name and number through my list. If the order number in the dictionary doesn't exist in the list it should be added to the end of the list. If the order number does exist it should not be added. Additionally, if the assignment was added it should return true and if not it should return false.

I'm really struggling to get started with this, any help would be appreciated. This is as far as I've gotten so far.

```
order_dict = {order_1: 29, order_4, 99} 
#I want to add order_4 to the end of my list of tuples
def add_order(customers)
    for c in customers:
```

Comment: Please format your question properly and add a plain Python tag

Comment: This is effectively a requirements dump. If you've made any attempts at all, post them. If not, explain your thoughts on excruciating detail, including a precise explanation of what is confusing here.

Comment: I'm struggling with understanding exactly where to begin. I just learned about the different data structures but all of this nesting is throwing me off.

Comment: Also, what you've posted here is simply not valid python code. You should probably fix that before anything else. It's very difficult to understand your data structure with all the mismatched braces. I think that's a large part of your problem.

Comment: I agree. This is the data set I was given to complete the problem.

Comment: `order_dict = {order_1: 29, order_4, 99}` is not valid python.  Is `order_1` supposed to be a string?  i.e. did you really mean `order_dict = {'order_1': 29, 'order_4': 99} `?

Comment: Yes, those should be strings. I'm thinking that I need to loop through all of the orders and check if the order_# is equal to the order_# in my dictionary.

Comment: In the `orders` list for each customer, what is the purpose of the first item in each tuple, i.e. `'order_1'`, `'order_2'` etc?

Comment: 'order_1' is used as an order name. The other value in the tuple is the dollar value of the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the `customers` list of dicts to look for a customer name matching that of the order. If the matching customer name is found, look for the matching order number, and if found, `break` out of `for-else` constructs to return `False`; if a matching order number is not found, append the order number to the `orders` key of the customer of the matching name. If no customer is found with a matching name, append to the `customers` list with the new order details and with an incremental `id`.

```
def add_order(customers, order):
    for customer in customers:
        if order['first_name'] == customer['first_name'] and order['last_name'] == customer['last_name']:
            for _, order_number in customer['orders']:
                if order['number'] == order_number:
                    break
            else:
                customer['orders'].append(('order_%d' % (len(customer['orders']) + 1), order['number']))
                return True
            break
    else:
        customers.append({
            'id': customers[-1]['id'] + 1 if customers else 1,
            'first_name': order['first_name'],
            'last_name': order['last_name'],
            'orders': [('order_1', order['number'])]
        })
        return True
    return False
```

so that:

```
customers = [{'id': 12345, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Anderson',
              'orders': [('order_1', 300), ('order_2', 255), ('order_3', 79)]},
             {'id': 12346, 'first_name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Smith',
              'orders': [('order_1', 400), ('order_2', 199), ('order_3', 49)]}]
print(add_order(customers, {'first_name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'number': 199}))
print(add_order(customers, {'first_name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'number': 200}))
print(add_order(customers, {'first_name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Brown', 'number': 201}))
from pprint import pprint
pprint(customers)
```

would output:

```
False
True
True
[{'first_name': 'John',
  'id': 12345,
  'last_name': 'Anderson',
  'orders': [('order_1', 300), ('order_2', 255), ('order_3', 79)]},
 {'first_name': 'Mary',
  'id': 12346,
  'last_name': 'Smith',
  'orders': [('order_1', 400),
             ('order_2', 199),
             ('order_3', 49),
             ('order_4', 200)]},
 {'first_name': 'Mary',
  'id': 12347,
  'last_name': 'Brown',
  'orders': [('order_1', 201)]}]
```